# access helper_method defined in controller in helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Im trying to access helper_method defined in controller in helper. This was working in rails 2.3 i assume. In rails 3/4 its not. Is that correct?

**application_controller.rb:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   helper_method :some_method

end
```

**application_helper.rb:**

```
module ApplicationHelper
   def use_some_method
      some_method # trying to use helper_method defined in controller which worked in rails 2.3?
   end
end
```

I get this error:

```
Error: undefined local variable or method `some_method' for...
```

If its not allowed anymore what is the right way to access the helper_method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defined the method in **application_helper.rb** as:-

```
module ApplicationHelper
 def use_some_method
  some_method
 end
 def some_method

 end
end
```

Delete **some_method** method from **application_controller.rb**

Delete this line also  from **application_controller.rb**:-

```
helper_method :some_method
```

Comment: i want the method accessible in controllers, views & helpers

Comment: methods in helper is accessible in controllers?

Comment: If you want to use it in controller then it should be defined in application_controller.rb

Comment: it will not accessible in controllers

Comment: but since methods defined in `helpers` are automatically available in your views, you can move the method from the `controller` to a `helper`.

Comment: ok i moved the method to module & included it in controller & helper separately. This make it accessible everywhere. hope this is a decent enough approach.

Comment: yes it will work and if it does then mark this answer as accepted so that other can know it worked.

Answer (score 0):

[According to the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html#method-i-helper_method), you can do this:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
Class YourController < ApplicationController
    helper_method :some_method

    def some_method
        "hello world"
    end
end
```

You *should* then be able to access this in your helper modules / classes. I appreciate you've probably tried this, and if it's not working, it's probably because your controller isn't loading

The most basic test I would do is to put it into `application_controller` (this is always called), and then see if you can access the method from your helper files

Comment: i had added it into application_controller and tried accessing it from application_helper. dint work. helper_method is accessible only to views i believe.